# SQL Server stored procedure doubling all values

Tags: sql, sql-server, left-join, inner-join

This is my stored procedure and it seems to be pulling all the correct values from the table but for some reason it is doubling all the hours which is in turn doubling all values. I have no idea where I'm going wrong here, any help would be much appreciated.

```
SELECT  
    FirstName, LastName,
    JobRegular.RegularHours AS RegularHours,
    JobRegular.RegularHours * dbo.Employees.Wage AS RegularPay,
    JobRegular.OvertimeHours AS OvertimeHours,
    JobRegular.OvertimeHours * dbo.Employees.Wage AS OvertimePay,
    JobOvertime.CBRegularHours AS CBRegularHours,
    JobOvertime.CBRegularHours * dbo.Employees.Wage AS CBRegularPay,
    JobOvertime.CBOvertimeHours AS CBOvertimeHours,
    JobOvertime.CBOvertimeHours * dbo.Employees.Wage AS CBOvertimePay
FROM 
    dbo.Employees
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT  
         dbo.EmployeeJobs.EmployeeId,
         SUM(dbo.EmployeeJobs.RegularHours) AS RegularHours,
         SUM(dbo.EmployeeJobs.RegularHours) * MIN(dbo.Employees.Wage) AS RegularPay,
         SUM(dbo.EmployeeJobs.OvertimeHours) As OvertimeHours, 
         SUM(dbo.EmployeeJobs.OvertimeHours) * MIN(dbo.Employees.Wage) As OvertimePay
     FROM 
         dbo.EmployeeJobs, dbo.Employees
     WHERE 
         dbo.EmployeeJobs.ComputerCodeId IN (7,8,9,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,22)
     GROUP BY 
         dbo.EmployeeJobs.EmployeeId) AS JobRegular ON dbo.Employees.EmployeeId = JobRegular.EmployeeId 
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT  
         dbo.EmployeeJobs.EmployeeId,
         SUM(dbo.EmployeeJobs.RegularHours) As CBRegularHours,
         SUM(dbo.EmployeeJobs.RegularHours) * MIN(dbo.Employees.Wage) AS CBRegularPay,
         SUM(dbo.EmployeeJobs.OvertimeHours) AS CBOvertimeHours,
         SUM(dbo.EmployeeJobs.OvertimeHours) * MIN(dbo.Employees.Wage) As CBOvertimePay
     FROM  
         dbo.EmployeeJobs, dbo.Employees
     WHERE 
         dbo.EmployeeJobs.ComputerCodeId IN (4,5,6)
     GROUP BY 
         dbo.EmployeeJobs.EmployeeId) AS JobOvertime ON dbo.Employees.EmployeeId = JobOvertime.EmployeeId
```

Comment: have you tried running the SP in SQL SERVER Management? where does the doubling occur? in the SP or in you Program code?

Comment: yes it doubles when I run it in SQL SERVER MANAGEMENT, I don't have it wired up to my program yet.

Comment: Why use a left join? Does Inner join produce a different and wrong data?

Comment: INNER doesn't show with null values. But that isn't what is causing the doubling.

Comment: Have you tried individually joining these two tables? As I see it now, you're joining regular workhours to employees and overtime to employee, you do know you could have atleast 2 overtimes in a day (morning and after work, depending on company policy)

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: thank you both, that was my issue. I had two employees and that's why it was doubling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sub queries (JobRegular, JobOvertime) have no join conditions - you are saying join EmployeeJobs to Employees, but haven't said how. So it does a cross join - every employee record joins with every jobs record. I'm surprised it's only doubling. You need something more like this - this is JobRegular, JobOvertime also needs fixing. (Also, start using table aliases, it will make this much more readable)

```
SELECT  dbo.EmployeeJobs.EmployeeId,
        SUM(dbo.EmployeeJobs.RegularHours) AS RegularHours,
        SUM(dbo.EmployeeJobs.RegularHours) * MIN(dbo.Employees.Wage) AS RegularPay,
        Sum(dbo.EmployeeJobs.OvertimeHours) As OvertimeHours, 
        SUM(dbo.EmployeeJobs.OvertimeHours) * MIN(dbo.Employees.Wage) As OvertimePay
FROM dbo.EmployeeJobs 
    inner join dbo.Employees on dbo.Employees.EmployeeId = dbo.EmployeeJobs.EmployeeId
WHERE dbo.EmployeeJobs.ComputerCodeId IN (7,8,9,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,22)
GROUP BY dbo.EmployeeJobs.EmployeeId
```

---

Edited - actually, you don't need employee in the subquery at all, remove it

```
SELECT  dbo.EmployeeJobs.EmployeeId,
        SUM(dbo.EmployeeJobs.RegularHours) AS RegularHours,
        SUM(dbo.EmployeeJobs.RegularHours) * MIN(dbo.Employees.Wage) AS RegularPay,
        Sum(dbo.EmployeeJobs.OvertimeHours) As OvertimeHours, 
        SUM(dbo.EmployeeJobs.OvertimeHours) * MIN(dbo.Employees.Wage) As OvertimePay
FROM dbo.EmployeeJobs 
WHERE dbo.EmployeeJobs.ComputerCodeId IN (7,8,9,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,22)
GROUP BY dbo.EmployeeJobs.EmployeeId
```